# Yii2 image submission

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I'm trying to register 2 uploaded images in the database and upload them to an 'upload' folder. It gives me #400 bad request as in "Unable to verify your data submission."
Any ideas on how to fix this? Below's my code.

```
Controller actionCreate():

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new PhotoCategories();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
        $model->thumbnail_image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'thumbnail_image');

        if ($model->upload()) {
            $model->save();
        }

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Model uses the ImageValidator. Here are the rules() and upload() functions:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'thumbnail_image', 'image', 'description'], 'required'],
            [['description'], 'string'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 256],
            [['name'], 'unique'],

            [['thumbnail_image'], 'image', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
            [['image'], 'image', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg']
        ];
    }

    public function upload() {

        if ($this->validate()) {

            $this->image->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension);
            $this->thumbnail_image->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

The View file for the form is as it follows:

```
<div class="photo-categories-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfParam; ?>" value="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfToken; ?>" />

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'thumbnail_image')->fileInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Even though I have also written the hidden input back there, it still throws me the error.

Comment: Are there any behaviors added in this controller? Why are you not checking if both `saveAs()` and `save()` methods returned `true`?

Comment: your controller and model code is fine, can u share your view code?

Comment: Yes, behaviors are already added to the model. Already checked if the save() and saveAs() methods return true, and they do.

Answer (score 0):

Yii won't allow CSRF is an abbreviation for cross-site request forgery default. so if you want disable CSRF checking then add below code in you controller

```
public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

for more information see this. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-best-practices.html#avoiding-csrf

Warning: Disabling CSRF will allow any site to send POST requests to your site. It is important to implement extra validation such as checking an IP address or a secret token in this case.

or

you need set as input value inside the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfParam; ?>" value="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfToken; ?>" />
```

Note:- this is better way to handle "Unable to verify your data submission." errors.

Comment: Used the hidden input - however, Yii also throws me the error. Also tried by disabling CSRF validation. Using this code, it marks my upload image inputs as empty after form submission